# Unhandled exception at line 23, column 1 in http://localhost:49997/Scripts/bootstrap.js jquery is undefined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am loading the `Register page` in which I refer the `jquery` files and `bootstrap.js`,but still I am getting the above error in the tile.

This is to load jquery before bootstrap.so in the `cshtml` page I am loading both, is this the right way to load all.

**Register.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.map"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
```

Comment: put your jquery cdn `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` at the top

Comment: I tried the same by placing the jquery-1.10.2.min.js at the top ...still the same error ..

Comment: jquuery does not exist, did you mean jQuery? >_<

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of **duplicates** in your script registration:

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.map"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
```

Sometimes, the browser doesn't like duplicates so much, it corresponds in bootstrap not working and jquery throwing exceptions.

Try to remove the duplicates, wherever you have a call to min.js and to .js of the same file, remove one of them so you will have, for example:

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.map"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing duplicates and using jQuery's noConflict() on some of your scripts.
Information how to do that [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)